# Show UISearchDisplayController at bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

guys. I need to implement our designer's model. Here, he has moved the search bar to the bottom on the screen and whenever the keyboard appears it is moved to the top of the keyboard. Now I would like to keep the UISearchDisplayController to get all the filtering functionallity. But seems it's not possible to change the searchbar and keep it there. I could adjust the initial frame, but then when editmode comes. The bar is lifted to top of the screen. Has anybody done this before? Or maybe an alternative control that I could use?.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why the downvote? Yes, it's possible to do it just with search bar. However there's not documentation on internet about doing this with SearchDisplay controller, which would be useful to save time... that's the reason for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a UISearchDisplay in your case, you will need to implement the component yourself from scratch. The good thing is that you can use a UISearchBar for that, and just implemente yourself the behaviour using the delegate.

[UISearchBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html)